# Laravel Calling Multiple Controllers from Form Submit

Tags: laravel, controller

I want to submit a form, and once that submit button is pressed, I run a bit of code.
During this 'bit of code', part of its job will be to create a student, and also create a lunch order. (information pulled from the form).

From what I've been reading, I should be aiming to use CRUD, which would mean I should have a Student Controller and a LunchOrderController.

I want to call the @store method in each controller.

If I was doing it the 'bad' way, the form would have [action="/students" method=POST].   And in that route, it would then call /lunchorder/ POST, and then return to a page (redirect('students')).

However, as above, I don't want to call a controller from a controller.  Therefore, the initial [action="/students" method=POST] should be something else instead, and this new entity will then call the StudentController, then call the LunchOrderController, then redirect('students').

But, I don't know what this new entity is, or should be, or how to link to it.

It is just a new route to a new controller which is ok to call other controllers from?
Or is there some other place I should be sending the form data to (maybe models?), to them call the controller?  Or am I way off base and need to take some steps back?

I'm fairly new to Laravel but am wanting to use best practice as much as possible. All my reading of other posts don't seem to explain it enough to get my head around how its meant to work.

Edit: Some code to give an idea of what I'm getting at.

**Student_edit.blade.php**

```
  <form action="/student" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <label>First Name</label><input name="firstname"  value="">
    <label>Last Name</label><input name="lastname"  value="">
    <label>Lunch Order</label>
    <select name="lunch_value" id="">
        <option value="1" >Meat Pie</option>
        <option value="2" >Sandwich</option>
        <option value="3" >Salad</option>
        <option value="4" >Pizza</option>
    </select>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/students', 'StudentController');
Route::resource('/lunchorder', 'LunchOrderController');
```

**Studentcontroller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Student::create(request(['firstname', 'lastname']));

    LunchOrderController::store($request, $student_id); //<- This isn't the correct syntax

    return redirect('/students');  

}
```

**LunchOrderController**

```
public function store(Request $request, $student_id)
    {

        LunchOrder::create(array_merge(request(['lunch_value']), ['student_id' => $student_id]));

        return null;  

    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't set  2 controllers to one route. You can use observer for this action. Or you can create a trait for luncorder functions and call that trait function from student controller and lunchorder controller. Or you can create event/listener.

Comment: can you post little code

Comment: You should do it on the lunchController at once because you should have control over your models and how they are created, think about this way: if your student will create and for some reason your lunch creation doesn't complete successfully you should be able to revert the created student back.

Comment: I have added some code as an example of what I am aiming for. As far as I understand, I want to keep to controller to sit in between any changes made to the SQL table.  I also don't want to be creating two different sets of data in the one controller.  There may be an instance where the Student is created separately, perhaps by an admin, where I would want to only create a student record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would create a 'Logic' Directory as: app/Logic. Some people prefer Repositories etc, but this is my preference.
For your specific requirement I'd create the following file:

app/Logic/StudentLogic.php

**StudentLogic**

```
<?php

namespace App\Logic\StudentLogic;

use App\Student;
use App\LunchOrder;

class StudentLogic
{
    public function handleStudentLunch(Request $request): bool
    {
        $student = Student::create(request(['firstname', 'lastname']));

        if(is_null($student)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        LunchOrder::create(array_merge(request(['lunch_value']), ['student_id' => $student->id]));

        return true;
    }
}
```

**StudentController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $logic = new StudentLogic();

    $valid = $logic->handleStudentLunch($request);
    if($valid) {
        return redirect('/students');  
    }
    abort(404, 'Student Not Found');

}
```

**ASSUMPTIONS**

Student is stored under App/Student & LunchOrder is stored under App\LunchOrder
You will also need to `use App\Logic\StudentLogic` in StudentController

The reason I'd split this out into a `Logic` file is because I do not like 'heavy' controllers. Also, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to acomplish here, but creating a student on the same request you create a LunchOrder seems like you're asking for trouble